# Create and manage own wordpress categories based on a role

Tags: php, wordpress

I`ve created a plugin that add a new role (blogger) that offers to the logged in user to manage ONLY own media and OWN posts (with a limited no of posts based on a "rank"). But now I also want the user to be able to manage ONLY own categories( also add new categories). Is this possible?

Comment: I'd start researching [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6599/12615)

Comment: Thanks! Really was a start for me and I also resolved the problem :)